# How to edit an specific subString in XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file for example that looks like this.

```
<file>
 <add key="1" val="great.me"/>
 <add key="2" val="notSoGreat"/>
 <add key="3" val="lessGreat.me/yey" />
 <add key="4" val="soGreat/yey" />
</file>
```

i would like to replace the value of those .me to .awesome.

ex: `<add key="1" val="great.me"/>`

to  `<add key="1" val="great.awesome"/>`

and

ex: `<add key="3" val="lessGreat.me/yey"`

to   `<add key="3" val="lessGreat.awesome/yey"`

can you help me guys? TIA

Comment: Please refere to How To Ask - what have you tried? What is the specific problem in your code that you are facing? What have you done to try and solve the problem

Comment: Stop [Feeding Vampires](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258208/5427842) guys!!

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
string oldText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
string newText = oldText.Replace("me", "awesome");
File.WriteAllText(filePath, newText, Encoding.UTF8);
xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //load xml from file
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"E:\test1.xml");

    // get a list of nodes - 
    XmlNodeList allnodes = doc.SelectNodes("/file/add");

    // loop through all nodes
    foreach (XmlNode node in allnodes)
    {
       // get "value"
       XmlAttribute attrValue= node.Attributes["value"];   
       attrValue.value = "something";// use replace here     

    }

    // save new xml or you can overwrite
    doc.Save(@"E:\test1New.xml");
```